# Determine if string is located in text file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some code that will determine if a string (and/or char array) is present in a text file, but I'm stuck here. Any advice? I'm also pretty new to c++ so it would be nice if you guys could keep it simple for me :) thanks

Okay so the following code is edited from what I previously posted, and I'm editing to provide further context. Firstly, I know this code doesn't work. Obviously. Second, the object of my task is to scan every line in the first text file (represented by char* puzzle) and determine if each line is a word (by checking if it is present in dict, which is also a text file). The issue is I don't know how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


void checker(char* puzzle, char* dict){
   int x;
   fstream newfile;
   newfile.open(puzzle, ios::in); 
   string tp;

   if (newfile.is_open()){ 
      while(getline(newfile, tp)){ 

        if ((x = tp.find(tp, 0)) != string::npos) {
           cout << "found '" << dict << " \n\n" << tp << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Not found \n\n";
        }

      }
      newfile.close(); 
   }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   checker(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Comment: `char cstr[tp.size() + 1];` is not valid c++. Also, you should use `std::string` instead of `char*`, it's much easier.

Comment: Even if that were valid C++, you haven't put anything in `tp` yet, so `tp.size()` is `0`. You would have to put that line after calling `getline()`.

Comment: What string are you searching for? `tp.find(cstr, 0)` makes no sense, since `cstr` is a copy of `tp`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be searching for `dict`, not `cstr`?

Comment: Yeah I know the code is awful and doesn't work properly, hence why I'm asking. Basically, I want to determine if each line in puzzle is a real word by checking if it is present in dict.

Comment: Any reasoning why you're mixing c++ `std::string` and c raw strings `char []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to make a copy of `tp()`.

You should be searching for `dict` with `tp.find()`, not `cstr`.

You can't know that the string is not found until you get to the end of the loop. You shouldn't print `Not found` on every line that doesn't match. Use a variable to record whether the string was found during the loop.

The default starting position in `find()` is `0`, there's no need to specify it explicitly.

```
void checker(char* puzzle, char* dict){
    fstream newfile;
    newfile.open(puzzle, ios::in); 

    if (newfile.is_open()){ 
        string tp;
        bool found = false;
        while(getline(newfile, tp)){ 
            if (tp.find(dict) != string::npos) {
                cout << "found '" << dict << "'\n\n" << tp << endl;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        newfile.close();
        if (!found) {
            cout << "Not found\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things can be improved:

- you can check for success of opening a file on the same line that constructs the `ifstream` object, and don't need to specify `in` explicitly - just use an `ifstream` instead of `fstream`
- function arguments you don't intend to change can be passed as `const`
- you can search for the text without copying anything to a local `char` array
- if you're going to print every match, you need to keep track of whether you've seen a match yet; so I introduce a `found` boolean; a `int num_matches = 0;` variable that gets increments (i.e. `++num_matches;`) each time there's a match is another option that captures a bit more information
- there's normally no need to explicitly `close` a stream - the destructor will do that for you as the `ifstream` object goes out of scope (i.e. after the `if`-statement body in which it's created)
- it's good to create things just as you're ready to use them - hence `while (std::string line; getline(file, line))`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void checker(const char* puzzle_filename, const char* search_term){
   if (auto file = std::ifstream{puzzle_filename}) {
      bool found = false;
      while (std::string line; getline(file, line)) { 
         if ((line.find(search_term)) != string::npos) {
            std::cout << "found '" << search_term << "' \n\n" << tp << std::endl;
            found = true;
         }
      }
      if (!found)
         std::cout << "Not found\n\n";
   }
   else
       std::cerr << "unable to open " << puzzle_filename << '\n';
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   checker(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```